# Google fonts blocked by Content Security Policy

Tags: content-security-policy, google-fonts

Hi i have some content security policy like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'nonce-MhqUJrKKq9' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.16/webfont.js;
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com/; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com/;
    object-src 'none'; base-uri 'none';">
```

I was try to allow a google fonts, but it give me this error:

webfont.js:17 Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700%7CRoboto:300,400,500,600,700' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com/".

so what can caused this error? i though i already exclude it from my policy.

Comment: Try google fonts without https , 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700%7CRoboto:300,400,500,600,700'

Comment: You need to use the `https` URL: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700%7CRoboto:300,400,500,600,700`. (The error message in the question indicate your code is calling the `http` URL.)

Comment: @ishwarchandratiwari ah thanks it work you can put in answer if you want to so i can select it.

Comment: @sideshowbarker ah thank you, i still testing on my local never thought that i would cause a trouble. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try google fonts without https , http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700%7CRoboto:300,400,500,600,700%27